# How to install numjs

Tags: node.js

I want to `npm install numjs` but after 6 hours searching for a solution I have the same problem, an error at the step where it needs to install sharp.

I tried to uninstall everything and reinstall but it still don't want to it. I tried a thousand of solutions that I already forgot but I don't success to do it. What can I try next?

The console output :

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 
1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Franck\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Franck\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v12.17.0\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Franck\Documents\CRMexperiment\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN crm@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.20.8 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.20.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Franck\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-01T13_57_14_910Z-debug.log
```

The errors in log file:

```
1066 error errno 1
1067 error sharp@0.20.8 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
1067 error Exit status 1
1068 error Failed at the sharp@0.20.8 install script.
1068 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: What is in the additional logs, as per the note at the bottom?

Comment: You mean in the debug log ? I wanted to push it here but I don't know how to do, if I copy/paste its content here my message will be unreadable because its very long.

Comment: Yes, please paste it here, in text format. You can select the most relevant part of it if you prefer.

Comment: If you could also post the console output above as text, that would be good - images are a problem for several reasons, mainly that readers can't copy+paste sections to help find useful articles on the web.

Comment: Okay , I succeded to do it ! I just past the error lines of the log because it can be paste entirely, that's why I took so much time, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [to update sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1668#issuecomment-486808156) to at least `0.22.1` in order for it to work. This has already been updated inside numjs on Apr 30, 2020 -- see this [commit](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs/commit/c5cad43b1e61f2b18a49ff28981421db3e400639#diff-7ae45ad102eab3b6d7e7896acd08c427a9b25b346470d7bc6507b6481575d519) but this is not the version available in npm (npm still serves sharp `0.20.3` i.e. Jun 13 2018 version of the [package.json](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs/blob/8bc3d8b5159a4a5aa69800de88fabe3fe35cc6b7/package.json), as the CI fails with newer sharp.

Since it's there in the master (main) branch, you can simply pull it from github like:

```
npm install https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs
yarn add https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that numjs is currently not supported on nodejs v12+ because of the sharp dependency. You need to switch to **node v10.x.x** or earlier, which can be done with nvm for example.